# Hiding border around items in UWP GridView

Tags: c#, uwp

Is there anyway to hide/disable the almost transparent border around items in a `GridView`?

I've tried

```
Gridlines="None"
```

But that doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by editing the default style of the `GridViewItem`.

Check the default style [here in the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299127.aspx). You can either make a copy and edit it in full or just change some of the parts using setters. You can then apply it directly:

```
<GridView>
    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
</GridView>
```

Or if you copy the style and mark it with `x:Key` attribute, you can set it using the `StaticResource` markup extension.

```
<GridView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CustomGridViewItem}" />
```

Comment: It should somehow, unfortunately I don't have my dev PC at me right now. Try setting the `FocusBorderBrush` to `Transparent` inside the `Style`'s `Template`. In case nothing works, please post a screenshot of which border you want to remove and I will check it out when I get back home